# WCF Validate Json Request before hitting method with IParamaterInspector

Tags: wcf

I'm maintaining and developing new services for an old API structure with WCF for Mobile App. I noticed that invalid values for field (for example string value for decimal field) throw an exception in deserialization step before hitting to method. I wanted to use IParamaterInspector to handle validation before hitting to method. But even after implementing all required steps it's not hitting to BeforeCall method. Looks like I'm missing a really important step.

```
public class ValidateParameterInspectorAttribute : Attribute, IParameterInspector, IOperationBehavior
{
    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
    }


    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
    }


    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(this);
    }


    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the usage of the attribute as following,

```
[OperationContract]
[ValidateParameterInspector]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
void TestMethod(TestRequest testRequest);
```

Comment: can you share more details: is the ValidateParameterInspectorAttribute is on the contract (interface) or on the implementation ?

Comment: I used the attribute in the contract. When I debug it, I can see that it hit to ApplyDispatchBehavior and add the current instance of attribute as a ParameterInspector. But even on first call, it's not hit to BeforeCall. I can supply if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a test and have a success but I separate IParameterInspector and   IOperationBehavior

Below is my code.

My model.

```
 [DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

ParameterInspector

```
 public class MyParameterInspector : IParameterInspector
{
    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs,objectreturnValue,   object correlationState)
    {

    }

public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        Employee ee = inputs[0] as Employee;
            ee.Name = "myname";
        return inputs;
    }
}
```

OperationBehavior

```
  public class ParameterInspectorOperationBehavior :Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(new MyParameterInspector());
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {

    }
}
```

ServiceContract

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IRestService
{
    [ParameterInspectorOperationBehavior]
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    void Get(Employee employee);
}
```

Service configuration

```
  <service name="Service.Rest.RestService">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:3721/employee" contract="ServiceInterface.IRestService" binding="webHttpBinding"></endpoint>
  </service>
```

Client configuration

```
<endpoint  name="RestParameterInspector" address="http://localhost:3721/employee" contract="ServiceInterface.IRestService" binding="webHttpBinding"
           behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"></endpoint>
 <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

The result

[image]

Comment: i notice you miss [OperationContract] maybe it's related